# C# UWP how to get the value of changed ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, combobox

In my .xaml file I have my combo box as below:

`<ComboBox Name="CLengthCombo" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="24"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="25"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="26" IsSelected="True"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="27"/>
 </ComboBox>`

how can I implement my ComboBox_SelectionChanged event so that I can get the content of the comboBoxItem which is changed by user when application is running? Is SelectionChanged event the correct even to use in this case? The below does not work:

`private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
{ string chosenItem = CLengthCombo.PlaceholderText; }`
 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like following

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var comboBoxItem = e.AddedItems[0] as ComboBoxItem;
            if (comboBoxItem == null) return;
            var content = comboBoxItem.Content as string;
            if (content != null && content.Equals("some text"))
            {
                //do what ever you want
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can check it as valid answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SelectedItem property of the combobox

```
(CLengthCombo.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.aspx#properties

Comment: Thanks bhmahler for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Get your combobox to work this, c.(...) has SelectedItem, SelectedText ...:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var c = sender as ComboBox;

    var item = c.(...);
}
```

Comment: please provide some explanation of the code, what is obvious to you might not be obvious to someone else