# UWP XAML ComboBox throws a StackOverflowException when an item is selected

Tags: xaml, combobox, uwp

My XAML ComboBox control is stuck in an endless loop when a selection is changed in the UI.  The ComboBox sets the value of the bound property.  When the property has changed, it raises a property changed event.  This in turn causes the databinder to update the property again. This keeps looping until I get a stack overflow exception.

```
                   <ComboBox x:Name="OriginCountryCode"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" SelectedValue="{x:Bind Mode=TwoWay, Path=ViewModel.OriginCountryCode}"  DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CountryCodes}"   />
```

The control is bound to the following properties.

```
    private static  Dictionary<string, string> _countryCodes = null;
    public Dictionary<string, string> CountryCodes
    {
        get
        {
            if (_countryCodes != null) return _countryCodes;

            _countryCodes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
            foreach (var culture in cultures)
            {
                var region = new RegionInfo(culture.LCID);
                _countryCodes[region.TwoLetterISORegionName] = region.DisplayName;
            }
            return _countryCodes;
        }
    }

    public string OriginCountryCode
    {
        get => _origin.CountryCode;
        set
        {
            _origin.CountryCode = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(OriginCountryCode));
        }
    }
```

This behavior is odd as all my other controls do not exhibit this behavior. The BAML generated connector code for the ComboBox is different. One is is updated when there's a focus change and the other when the SelectedValue changes.

```
            case 15: // Views\QuotesPage.xaml line 77
                this.obj15 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox)target;
                (this.obj15).LostFocus += (global::System.Object sender, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    if (this.initialized)
                    {
                        // Update Two Way binding
                        this.dataRoot.ViewModel.DestinationPostalCode = this.obj15.Text;
                    }
                };
                break;
            case 16: // Views\QuotesPage.xaml line 78
                this.obj16 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBox)target;
                (this.obj16).RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectedValueProperty,
                    (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject sender, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty prop) =>
                    {
                    if (this.initialized)
                    {
                        // Update Two Way binding
                        this.dataRoot.ViewModel.DestinationCountryCode = (global::System.String)this.obj16.SelectedValue;
                    }
                });
                break;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't raise `PropertyChanged` when the property value hasn't changed.

```
public string OriginCountryCode
{
    get => _origin.CountryCode;
    set
    {
        if (_origin.CountryCode != value)
        {
            _origin.CountryCode = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(OriginCountryCode));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this is obviously the answer, but I had to put it up here to see if anyone ran into it.  It appears this is a bug.  The "proper" way to get around this is to use a command, but that's a lot of code just to get a value.

Comment: @ATL_DEV *"The "proper" way to get around this is to use a command"* -- No, it isn't. The proper way to bind a dependency property to a viewmodel property is to bind it, and put that equal check in the viewmodel property setter to prevent recursion. How would you use a command for any part of this?

Comment: Thanks. So what you are saying is that this behavior is a bug?  I believe so.  The equality check is not required for any other control even for the ones that generate the same binding code like switch buttons. I was thinking a command responding to eventchange would be the "recommended" way, but after your comment, I think this may just be a bug. Normally, .NET apis throws specific usage exceptions, instead of StackOverflowException or AccessFaultException.

Comment: @ATL_DEV You’re the WPF expert, so I’ll have to take your word for it. If you ever find the time to explain how you did this with a command, I’m curious.

Comment: Well, you can repond to the SelectionChanged event.  Here's a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623733/c-sharp-uwp-how-to-get-the-value-of-changed-comboboxitem

Comment: @ATL_DEV So that’s the correct MVVM way to do this. I always wondered. Thanks!

Comment: It isn't the correct way to do it.  It just is another way to do it if you need a little more control.  Using plain old databinding should be sufficient for the vast majority of cases as it is automatic and requires minimal code.

Comment: @ATL_DEV I'm glad I ran into you, I'm really learning a lot this morning. Above, you said *"The 'proper' way to get around this is to use a command"* -- can you add some depth to that remark?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158780/discussion-between-atl-dev-and-ed-plunkett).